# Install pyspark for beginner

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, installation

I am currently doing pyspark courses in data camp, and now would like to start trying to build some of my own projects on my own computer using pyspark. However, I am becoming massively confused with the installation of spark/pysaprk itself and how to run it in jypter notebook.

I have looked vids on youtube with regards to install, like edurkea which seems to give an installation by creating a vm machine and connecting it to another which I do not want all I want is to install pysaprk on my laptop locally.

I have also followed the installation instructions from this link :

https://medium.com/@brajendragouda/installing-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-pyspark-on-juputer-ca8e40e8e655

And when I run the command pyspark in my terminal I get the no command response.

I have looked at the documentation on the spark site, which I find not very newbie friendly and was wondering if anyone has a link to an easy to follow guide for this install.

My current OS is ubuntu the latest version, I am just learning at the moment about using shell and bash scripts at the present but it all very new and a lot of the stuff I been looking at is starting to confuse me.

Any links, advice would be much appreactied.

Comment: Spark can run on Windows too. Why do you need to learn shell scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [docker pyspark image](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook) that makes the setup pretty easy. Here's [a link describing the setup process](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-docker-and-pyspark-134cd4cab867). With docker installed & running, entering the following command line will launch a jupyter notebook environment in which you can run pyspark `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook`.

This command will mount a temporary filesystem, though, which makes reading/saving data difficult. To point the environment to your filesystem, run `docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -p 4040:4040 -p 4041:4041 -v /Users/your/path:/home/jovyan jupyter/pyspark-notebook`

Answer (score 1):

I've tried installing pyspark in several ways, but the easiest way to install was using conda.

If you have anaconda (miniconda) installed on your laptop, try installing as below.

```
conda install pyspark
conda install -c anaconda openjdk  
#anaconda channel has v.8 and it works best, and do not install from conda-forge for it's version 11 and it crashes
```

Add SPARK_HOME variable : Modify this and copy paste it into .bashrc file.

`export SPARK_HOME="/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark"`

This worked for me. You probably want to install `findspark` which can be found in conda easily.